# How to mock a method from an instance that is returned by another function

Tags: python, mocking

I wonder how I can mock the `verify_token` method in the `create_bucket` function so it raises an Exception.

*other_module.py*

```py
# ...

def get_connection(backend=None, **kwargs):
    klass = import_string(backend or settings.BACKEND)
    return klass(**kwargs)
```

*module.py*

```py
from other_module import get_connection


def create_bucket():
    conn = get_connection()

    # ...

    try:
        conn.verify_token()
    except VerificationFailed:
        #...
```

*tests.py*

Tests produce the error message

```
AttributeError: module.create_bucket.get_connection does not have the attribute 'verify_token'
```

```py
def test_create_bucket_with_failed_verification(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(
        "module.get_connection",
        "verify_token",
        side_effect=VerificationFailed
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by mocking the whole `get_connection` function:

```py
mocker.patch(
    "module.get_connection",
    return_value=mocker.Mock(verify_token=mocker.Mock(side_effect=VerificationFailed)),
)
```